# Emailing photo taken with ImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone

In my app I want to:
a.) Present camera to user to take picture
b.) Create email and attach picture taken

I figured out how to take the picture. But, I don't know how to attach it to the email. In the examples I've seen the filename is known. This is one example.

```
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
     [picker setSubject:@"I have a pencil for you"];

     UIImage *roboPic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RobotWithPencil.jpg"];
     NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(roboPic, 1);
     [picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"RobotWithPencil.jpg"];

     NSString *emailBody = @"This is a cool image of a robot I found.  Check it out!";
     [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

     [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

I am getting the image from the callback method and it does get stored in the camera roll.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
    [picker release];
     }
```

But from there, I'm not sure how to attach the image to the email? Mainly because I don't know what the filename is when a photo is added to the camera roll when the UIImagePickerController camera source is used to obtain it?

So, I guess I need to either:
a.) Find a way to get the name of the image file once it is saved OR
b.) Another way to attach UIImage data as an email attachment.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do UI wise, but why would this not work from your code provide:

EDIT: (changed code to use a delegate)

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagepicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


// Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectImage:)])
     [delegate didSelectImage:image];
 }
```

this goes in your header file (usually above your class declaration):

```
@protocol PostHelperDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)DimissModal;
//image data for image selected
- (void)DidSelectImage:(UIImage*)image;
@end
```

also you need to create this property in your class

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)id<PostHelperDelegate>* delegate; //don't forgot to synthizie
```

then in the class implementing the delegate you will assign the delegate your class:

```
    Poster = [[delegateclass alloc] init];
    Poster.delegate = self;
```

then just add the delegate function:

```
 - (void)DidSelectImage:(UIImage*)image
 {
   //handle image here
 }
```

I simplify this quite a bit, let me know if you have any trouble getting it working

http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/

BEFORE UPDATE:

personally I would use a delegate to notify that the image has been picked and than launch the mail picker, but that is another thing. As far as the UIImage, I don't know a way or have never found a way to name/or get a name from the UIImagePicker as I do not believe they are named anything meaningful. Any questions on the delegate or further explanation let me know.

Comment: I did add this snippet into the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. However, it is still not working as expected. One thing missing was the MailPicker declaration itself. So, I added that. However, it is never displayed. Not sure why? The code I added was this:     

MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

Comment: I think the delegate suggestion is needed. Part of the problem was dealing with two modal view controllers and trying to close the ImagePicker and then open the MailPicker from the above event.

Comment: I updated the code above to show how to do a delegate. I would also recommend opening the mailpicker view first then from there opening image picker view after the one is open. You will always have a problem with trying to close a modal view then immediately open another one, due to the way the iOS navigation works (also it could trip users up with a bunch of modal views going up and down).

Answer (score 0):

use bellow code

```
    -(void)yourmethodname_clicked{
        UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                picker.delegate = self;
        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {
                 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        }
        else{
                 UIAlertView *altnot=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Camera Not            Available" message:@"Camera Not Available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

                 [altnot show];
                 [altnot release];

        }
    }


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


MFMailComposeViewController *mailpicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    [mailpicker.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    mailpicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailpicker setSubject:@"set your subject"]; 

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil];

    [mailpicker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    UIImage *picture = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]];;

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture);
    [mailpicker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"set your file name"];

    NSString *emailBody = @"set your body string";
    [mailpicker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
    [mailpicker setSubject:@"set your subject"];
    mailpicker.title = @"Email";

    [self presentModalViewController:mailpicker animated:YES];
    [mailpicker release];
}
```

may this help you